# What is a best way to check if an element is visible when the page loads or there is a change in page, using Mutation Overserver?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, browser-extension, mutation-observers

I am working on a simple Chrome Extension with Manifest V3, where I am using Mutation Observer to check if the element is visible or not. It checks when the page loads and every time when there is a change in the page. If element is visible then I am injecting a button in the page using a function.
I am either using Query Selector or Class Name, which are both separate functions to get the element as different website requirements.

Here is the code:

```
function findSelectorPlaceholder(selector) {
  const observerS = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
      if (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
          const elm = mutation.addedNodes[i].querySelector(selector);
          if (elm && window.getComputedStyle(elm).display !== "none") {
            console.log("Element is visible!");
            placeBtn();
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
  observerS.observe(document.body, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
  });
}


function findClassPlaceholder(cName) {
  const mutationObserver1 = new MutationObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entries) => {
      if (entries.addedNodes.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < entries.addedNodes.length; i++) {
          if (entries.addedNodes[i].className == cName) {
            console.log("Class Found!");
            placeBtn();
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
  mutationObserver1.observe(document.body, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
  });
}
```

Now, the extension runs smoothly as expected for both functions. However every time Mutation Observer is triggered with the Query Selector, I get `mutation.addedNodes[i].querySelector is not a function` error in the extension debugger.

I tried to look through the error and even tried to implement the function in different ways. However, if the function changes, it not working as expected with either more errors or unexpected results.

I would appreciate if someone shade a light into how to best implement this. I would also like to know if there is better way to merge both the functions to achieve the same results. I tried but it's breaking the code.

Thank you!

Comment: Some of the added nodes aren't elements but just text nodes, so they don't have querySelector method.

Comment: @wOxxOm so is there a way to circumvent it?

Comment: Add `?` so it looks like `?.querySelector`

Comment: @wOxxOm Nope, still the same error

Comment: I guess you didn't replace it for all querySelector calls or maybe you didn't reload the extension on chrome://extensions page. Also note that this page shows old errors from old code, so you may need to press the `Clear all` button to remove them.

Comment: @wOxxOm nope, I did clear it every time, made sure that I made right calls for all and reloaded it every time.

Comment: Well, it should be in a different place, sorry: `addedNodes[i].querySelector?.(`